# Nodejs Keep-alive with Unix Domain sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, unix

Keep-alive works just fine over TCP. But Unix Domain Sockets gives me weird behavior. If I send a couple thousand requests like this:

```
request.post('http://unix:/tmp/http.sock:/check', {
  json: {
     ...
    },
  forever: true,
  pool: {maxSockets: 10},
  headers: {
    'Host': '',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
  })
```

a kernel trace will show 2000 sockets being created (and never closed), one for each request. I'd expect only 10 sockets to be created and reused as necessary.

Is there a way to set things up so unix sockets are kept alive and reused the same way TCP sockets are?

Comment: Keepalive is used to prevent a remote connection from timing out but unix sockets are local to the computer and the OS knows what's going on with both ends so, no, sockets do not have or need keepalive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior is broken in Node prior to version v8.7.0. A [commit by user bengl](https://github.com/nodejs/node/commit/9c1e48dca53720e1788be7394fadac66904dd068) fixing keep-alive for Unix domain sockets was put into the v8.7.0 build. That build was released about 6 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

From the `request` documentation:

> Note that if you are sending multiple requests in a loop and creating multiple new pool objects, maxSockets will not work as intended. To work around this, either use request.defaults with your pool options or create the pool object with the maxSockets property outside of the loop.

So it seems like you need to create the pool object outside the loop in order for sockets to be reused as you expect.

Comment: The code in this case isn't making multiple new pool objects, it ends up using the global agent as the pool each time. Also, it works just fine for regular HTTP over TCP.

Comment: @allenluce can you post the TCP response you captured from the socket?  I am wondering if it is sending the keep-alive by mistake.

Comment: While the keep-alive header was being sent, it was also persisting the sockets. I could see in a system call trace that `socket()` was only being called a few times instead of for every connection. Check the answer I just posted.